# Angularjs : Default value setting inside controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a question regarding the angularjs set value and reset it to default.

Here an example

```
$scope.defaultValue = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}
var dupValue = $scope.defaultValue;

...

function changeValue() {
    dupValue.b = 3;
}

...
```

After I execute the function `changeValue()`, I wish to change my `dupValue` back to `defaultValue` which I simply just call

```
dupValue = $scope.defaultValue;
```

Some how it did't work. Because the `defaultValue`'s element has changed due to the function i executed.

Is there any method to make this work?

Comment: Please post the DOM where these values are bound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'are not copying the defaultValue, but just assigning the reference to it. Therefore when you modify dupValue you also make change to defautValue.

Assign default value using:

```
dupValue = angular.copy($scope.defaultValue);
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0jx6sx5r/)

Comment: It work great on my side now, got confused among copying and assigning variable in coding, thanks anyway